# KeyListener is not being called

Tags: java, graphics, keylistener

In class we are tasked with recreating the game Space Invaders. Right now I'm just working on my getting my spaceship to move across the bottom. I've been using the debugger but when I press the arrows my keyPressed method is not being called.

```
package testprogram;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class TestFrame extends JFrame{
    public TestFrame(){
        setBackground(Color.white);
        Test2 t2 = new Test2();
        this.add(t2);
        t2.repaint();
    }
private class Test2 extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    int width;
    int height;
    DrawObject object;
    public Test2(){
    setSize(500,500);
    setBackground(Color.black);
    this.width = this.getWidth();
    this.height = this.getHeight();
    object= new DrawObject(getWidth(), getWidth());
    addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        object.draw(g);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k){
        int key = k.getKeyCode();
        if(key == k.VK_LEFT){//if left arrow is pressed
            object.moveLeft();
            repaint();
        }
        if(key == k.VK_RIGHT){//if right arrow is pressed
            object.moveRight();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k){
        //dummy method
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k){
       //used for launching projectile 
    }
    //used to call draw methods
}
private class DrawObject{
    int pnlWidth;
    int pnlHeight;
    int moveInc =5;

    public DrawObject(int pnlWidth, int pnlHeight){
        this.pnlWidth=pnlWidth;
        this.pnlHeight=pnlHeight;
    }
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        Point loc = new Point();
        //bottom right point
        loc.x=pnlWidth;
        loc.y=pnlHeight;
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
        triangle.addPoint(loc.x, loc.y);//bottom right point
        triangle.addPoint(loc.x-50, loc.y);//bottom left point
        triangle.addPoint(loc.x-25, loc.y-50);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillPolygon(triangle);
    }
        //moves canon left
    public void moveLeft(){
        if(getLocation().getX()>0 && getLocation().getX()<pnlWidth)
            getLocation().translate(-moveInc, 0);
    }
    //moves canon right
    public void moveRight(){
        if(getLocation().getX()<pnlWidth && getLocation().getX()>0)
            getLocation().translate(moveInc, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

I've isolated the key parts to this test class. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [Many similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=swing+keylistener+not+working+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F).

Comment: Likely for the same reason why every question about "key listener not working" - they only respond to components which are focusable AND have focus.  Use the key bindings API instead. See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)